# Выбор версии phpmyadmin при установке

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin

Мой сервер ubuntu 20 использует apache2 и php 7.4. При обычной установке `sudo apt install phpmyadmin` устанавливается phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 которая работает только на php 8. Как я могу выбрать версию phpMyAdmin, не повышая версию php на сервере?

Comment: А если после phpmyadmin  нажать TAB  что будет показано? обычно TAB для автокомплита, а также если есть множественные варианты то терминал показывает его

Comment: Для такой команды ничего не будет показано.

Comment: Кто сказал что 5.2.0 работает только на php 8?

Comment: Прямого упоминания на сайте нет, но на практике - так и есть. Об этом есть обсуждения в репо phpmyadmin

Comment: у меня на php 7.3 стоит 5.2.0 и всё работает. а версию указывать можно если ставить с гита или через composer

Comment: В логах я получаю ошибку PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272, которая приводит к ответу 500. static в качестве возвращаемого типа методы класса используется в php 8. Как Вы тогда решили эту проблему?

Comment: @AntonBogomolov ну так здесь проблема не в phpMyAdmin, а, судя по всему, в Symfony. Код не трогали?